# Unable to drag and drop Outlet to my View Obj-C iOS development.

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am facing a weird problem that i do not understand. I have outlet displaying in Outlet tab but when i try do drag and drop it, it does not appear and thus i am unable to use it. I haven't faces such issue before so help appreciated. [image]

As you can see on image when i try to drag either directly from File's owner or from the Outlet tab the "pointobject" which i want to use does not appear. 

In my ViewController you will find this

```
#import "PointObject.h"
@interface LandscapeViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, 

UITableViewDataSource, PointObjectDelegate>
{
    // not relevant code up here
    //----------------------------------------
    /*
     * for graph
     */
    LandscapeGraphViewController * landscapeGraphViewController;
    IBOutlet PointObject  *pointObject;
    IBOutlet UIButton *ZoomIn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *ZoomOut;

} 
// not relevant code below
```

In my PointObject.h you will find this

```
@class PointObject;

@protocol PointObjectDelegate

-(double)expressionResultForXValue: (CGFloat)x requestor: (PointObject *)pointObject;

@end

@interface PointObject : UIView
{
    id<PointObjectDelegate> delegate;
    CGFloat scale;
    CGPoint originOffset;
}

-(void)reset;

@property (assign) id <PointObjectDelegate> delegate;
```

Some code has been cut out as it is not relevant to the question. Thank you

Comment: Where are you trying to connect `pointObject` to?

Comment: @Espresso to a view (i have one view on left about 30% of screen, and other view on right taking 70% of the screen) and i am trying to connect it to the right view

Comment: @Espresso Ok nvm ... i have fixed it, just forgot to add custom class to that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have assigned class `PointObject` to a view, you want to use as `PointObject`

Just see following image...

[image]

As shown in image select your view which is used as `PointObject` then in third tab of property window assign class `PointObject` .
Hope it will help you........

Comment: Yes i already figure it out yesterday if you look at comments above :) i did say that i have forgot to state class for that view. But thx for effort anyway :)